# Money in the box - How much would you pay to play this game?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I came across this interview question of Glassdoor, but it seems to be very interesting, yet tricky to me:

> There is some amount of money in a box, determined in the following way: 200 fair coins are flipped. Let the number of heads that come up be H. The amount of money put in the box is H*(100-H)/100. How much would you pay for the box?

Considering that X is the number of heads obtained after 200 flips, E[X] = 100, which would yield a profit of 0. However, I feel there is more to this problem. Maybe it's still worth playing and hope for values with a big enough probability (close to 100, but different), which would yield a non-zero payout.

Can anyone shed some light on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $H=100+x$ has the same probability as $H=100-x$, for all applicable $x$. The first is worth $\frac{-x(100+x)}{100}$, the second $\frac{x(100-x)}{100}$, so on average $-\frac{x^2}{100}$. Combining all $x$ (by their respective positive probabilities), the result is certainly negative!

For the exact (negative) value, you need to find out $E[X^2]$ from the *variance* of $X$. We know
$E[X]=200\cdot \frac12=100$ and $V[X]=200\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12=50$, and as
$$V[X]=E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2,$$
we have $E[X^2]=10050$ and

$$ E[X(100-X)/100]=E[X]-\frac1{100}E[X^2]=100-\frac{10050}{100}=-0.5$$